# ArrayOutOfBoundException while inserting elements

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` while inserting elements to a two Dimensional array..I dont know where the problem is..
I tried a lot but couldn't understand why this is giving the exception.Here is my code..Thanks in advance..

```
public class TruthTableAutoMateClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

static int size;

private int i = 0;

static JButton btnOk = new JButton();

String[][] array= new String[size][];

private double[][] dim = { {0.50, 0.50}, {0.25, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, TableLayout.FILL}};


public static void main(String args[])
{
    TruthTableAutoMateClass auto = new TruthTableAutoMateClass();
    checkAdding(auto);
    btnOk.addActionListener(auto);
}

private static String[] prepareArray()
{
    String[] arr = new String[2];

    if (size == 16)
    {

        String text1 = field1.getText();
        String text2 = field2.getText();
        String text3 = field3.getText();
        String text4 = field4.getText();

        String firstArray = new StringBuilder().append(text1).append("|").append(text3).append("|").append(text3).append("|").append(text4).toString();

        arr[0] = firstArray;
        arr[1] = ledValue1.getText();

    }
    else if (size == 9)
    {

    }
    else if (size == 4)
    {

    }

    return arr;
}

private static void checkAdding(TruthTableAutoMateClass auto1)
{
    TruthTableAutoMateClass auto = auto1;
    String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many values are there 4 or 3 " + "if 4 yes else press no");

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {

        size = 4 * 4;
        auto.add(lbl1, "0,0");
        auto.add(lbl2, "0,1");
        auto.add(lbl3, "0,2");
        auto.add(lbl4, "0,3");

        auto.add(field1, "1,0");
        auto.add(field2, "1,1");
        auto.add(field3, "1,2");
        auto.add(field4, "1,3");

        auto.add(ledValue1, "1,4");
        /*auto.add(ledValue2);
        auto.add(ledValue3);
        auto.add(ledValue4);*/

        auto.add(btnOk, "0,4");

    }
    else
    {
        size = 3 * 3;
        String answer2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Again enter yes or no" + "3 for yes , 2 for no");
        if (answer2.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            auto.add(lbl1, "0,0");
            auto.add(lbl2, "0,1");
            auto.add(lbl3, "0,2");
            auto.add(field1, "1,0");
            auto.add(field2, "1,1");
            auto.add(field3, "1,2");

            auto.add(ledValue1, "1,4");
            /* auto.add(ledValue2);
             auto.add(ledValue3);*/

            auto.add(btnOk, "0,4");
        }
        else
        {
            size = 2 * 2;
            auto.add(lbl1, "0,0");
            auto.add(lbl2, "0,1");

            auto.add(field1, "1,0");
            auto.add(field2, "1,1");

            auto.add(ledValue1, "1,4");
            /* auto.add(ledValue2);*/
            auto.add(btnOk, "0,4");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    array[i] = prepareArray();

    i++;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}}
```

Comment: The first step is to read the stack trace, and the documentation of the exception. Not posting the stack trace forces us to guess, and to scrutate your whole wall of mostly irrelevant code, instead of focusing on where the problem is. It's valuable information. Don't neglect it.

Comment: @JBNizet    ArrayOutofbound exception occurs when am trying to acces something out of bounds , but in my code am not trying to access out of bounds.could you please tell me y ?

Comment: Have you read my previous comment? Doesn't it insist on the importance of reading the stack trace of the exception? How could I read it if you don't post it?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at abc.TruthTableAutoMateClass.actionPerformed(TruthTableAutoMateClass.java:172)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: array[i] = prepareArray(); at this line exception is getting raised

Comment: OK. So you now have the line. You also have the incorrect index: 0. So you need to wonder why 0 is an invalid index for the array `array`. Where is the array initialized? `String[][] array= new String[size][];`. So, what is the value of `size`?. `static int size;` So it's 0. So you created an empty array, and trying to get its first element. An empty array doesn't have a first element, hence the exception. Do you understand the train of thought? Do you understand how it all starts by reading the exception stack trace?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148674/discussion-between-java-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the `main()` method you are creating an instance of `TruthTableAutoMateClass`. When this one is creating, `size = 0` (by default) and `String[][] array= new String[size][];` creates an array with size 0.

So, your array had size 0 and you got an exception when you had tried to assign some value like this `array[i] = prepareArray();`.